# Recursively get all children

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to recursively get all children from a nested object.
I already wrote a function that does it (kinda) but I think it can be improved.

**How can I make it shorter and cleaner?**

I have included the data I'm using for testing as well as the function I wrote that needs improvement.

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    child: {
      id: 2,
      child: {
        id: 3,
        child: {
          id: 4,
          child: null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    child: {
      id: 6,
      child: null
    }
  }
];


// function

for (let cat of data) {
  cat.children = getCategoryChild(cat);
  console.log(cat.children)
}

function getCategoryChild(cat) {
  let t = [];

  if (cat.child != null) {
    t.push(cat.child);

    let y = getCategoryChild(cat.child);
    if (y.length > 0) {
      for (let i of y) {
        t.push(i)
      }
    }
  }

  return t;
}
```

Expected output:

`[{id: 1, children: [{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]}, {id: 5, children: [{id: 6}]}]`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and after you fix the comma there `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`, seems not to work at the moment

Comment: @Carla do you want all the children in single-dimensional array?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'v fixed the problem.

Comment: does each category only ever have one child?  The code implies that it does, I just want to make sure of it

Comment: @Carla show your expected output.

Comment: Since you're asking for help improving working code, this may be a better fit over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but be sure to take their tour and read their help first, particularly [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: _"I already wrote a function that does it (kinda)"_ What do you mean by _"kinda"_? Can you include the expected result in the question? What is the issue with the code?

Comment: @guest271314 It actually works fine.

Comment: Yes, you can probably shorten the code. Not certain what _"cleaner"_ means. It is not clear what the expected output is. If the code does not have issues consider asking the question at code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, including a description of what the code does and expected output in the body of the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: do you have som children arrays inside?

Comment: @NinaScholz What I want: `[{id: 1, children: [{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]}, {id: 5, children: [{id: 6}]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that each category only ever has one child

edited to adhere to the expected result...

```
function iterChildren(cat) {
  let c = cat, children = [];

  while (c.child) {
    children.push({id: c.child.id});
    c = c.child;
  }

  return {id: cat.id, children: children};
}

let newData = data.map(iterChildren);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a recursive approach by checking the actual `child` property

```js
function convert(array) {
    const iter = o => o ? [{ id: o.id }, ...iter(o.child)] : [];
    return array.map(({ id, child }) => ({ id, children: iter(child) }));
}

var data = [{ id: 1, child: { id: 2, child: { id: 3, child: { id: 4, child: null } } } }, { id: 5, child: { id: 6, child: null } }];

console.log(convert(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not what I want. I want something like `[{id: 1, children: [{id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]}, {id: 5, children: [{id: 6}]}]`

Comment: I edited the question and added the expected result.

Comment: This is great, but nigh illegible to a novice developer :-) uses too many newfangled advanced concepts

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote the function.
It filters cats, and only returns an object with `id` and `child_id` of each.

```js
let output = [],
    data = [{
        id: 1,
        child: {
          id: 2,
          child: {
            id: 3,
            child: {
              id: 4,
              child: null
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        child: {
          id: 6,
          child: null
        }
      }
    ];

function getCategoryChild(cat) {
  var t = [{
    id: cat.id,
    child_id: null
    /* HERE you can set, what kind of data should be included to output */
  }]
  if (cat.child) {
    t[0].child_id = cat.child.id
    t = t.concat(getCategoryChild(cat.child))
  }
  return t
}

for (x of data) {
  output=output.concat(getCategoryChild(x))
}

console.log(output)
```

EDIT: I edited my code assuming that one cat can have more children:

```js
let output = [],
  data = [{
      id: 1,
      child: {
        id: 2,
        child: {
          id: 3,
          child: {
            id: 4,
            child: null
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      child: {
        id: 6,
        child: null
      }
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      child: [
        {
          id: 8,
          child: {
            id: 9,
            child: null
          }
        }, 
        {
          id: 10,
          child: null
        }, 
        {
          id: 11,
          child: null
        }
      ]
    },
  ];

function getCategoryChild(cat) {
  var t = [{
    id: cat.id,
    child_id: []
    /* HERE you can set, what kind of data should be included to output */
  }]
  if (cat.child) {
    if (!(cat.child instanceof Array)) {
      cat.child = [cat.child]
    }
    for (var x of cat.child) {
      t[0].child_id.push(x.id)
      t = t.concat(getCategoryChild(x))
    }
  }
  return t
}

for (x of data) {
  output = output.concat(getCategoryChild(x))
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data.map(({id,child:c})=>({id,children:[...{*0(){for(;c&&({id}=c);c=c.child)yield{id}}}[0]()]}))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code such that the OP can learn what it does

Comment: @Carla shorter `(;c;c=c.child)yield{id:c.id}`